# PHP <?=foo() ?> not working

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

PHP short syntax for echo `<?=foo()?>` is not working while short_open_tags is enabled. I'm running Centos6:

```
Linux pau.pauperis.com 2.6.35.11-83.9.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 19 23:42:04 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

php 5.3:

```
PHP 5.3.8 (cli) (built: Sep 25 2011 11:33:49)
```

Apache 2.2:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.20 (Unix)
```

Placing  `echo "<pre>";print_r(ini_get_all());die();` in a .php files gives the following:

```
    [short_open_tag] => Array
        (
            [global_value] => 1
            [local_value] => 1
            [access] => 6
        )
```

`phpinfo();` tells `short_open_tags` are `on`:

```
egrep -Ri 'short_open' .
./php.ini:; short_open_tag
./php.ini:short_open_tag = On
```

Thanks a lot for the answers!
By not working i mean to say PHP code is not parsed. It acts as i had no PHP support for apache. Try writting  with short_open_tags disabled and that's what i see. `<? echo foo() ?>` works fine. There are no errors at apache's log.

I know short tags are not recommended but they're used on a big CodeIgniter project, which i can't change. Does anyoen knows what could be failing?

Thx in advanced!

Comment: Define "not working". Your question doesn't state what is actually happening.

Comment: What is the error? All you've shown us is something that should work: http://codepad.org/74Gtq53l

Comment: And `foo()` returns a printable value? does `<?php echo foo(); ?>` work?

Comment: Your edit doesn't make sense; does `<? echo foo() ?>` work? That is a short tag.

Comment: You might reinstall PHP. Everything looks right, so the only thing I can say is that the actual PHP installation is wrong. I can't think of any reason why the `echo` shortcut with short tags alone wouldn't work.

Comment: It's like that man, it's just failing for <?=foo()?>, really strange.

Answer (score 2):

The local flags can differ from what `phpinfo()` promised you. PHP settings may be overriden via `.htaccess` or `.user.ini` files.

To probe which are actually active, add this in your template script:

```
<?php print_r(ini_get_all()); ?>
```

It's impossible for anyone here to tell what's going on on your system. You need to debug this yourself.